# Event to tell you that an element has been appended to the document?

Tags: javascript, html

There are some attributes of an html element that cannot be figured out until it is in the HTML DOM such as offsetHeight or offsetWidth.  If I createElement('div') and want to use the div's offsetHeight, is there an event that fires when this element is appended to the document so that I know I can now use offsetHeight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DOMNodeInserted`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted) might be what you are looking for.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference for details about DOM events

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` does work in current browsers but not in IE < 9 and likely not in browsers released a few years from now, since DOM mutation events are deprecated and will be replaced with [mutation observers](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers). It's the best you can do for now though.

Comment: @TimDown, can you point me to the article where it says such and such features of html/javascript are to be deprecated (want to see what to look out for).  Also, in this case, what would you recommend doing? What are the mutation observer events? How/can I use mutation observers now?

Comment: @Derek: [Mutation events in DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) mentions mutation events being deprecated, [as does the current work-in-progress DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#goals). I heard about this from the [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/mailing-list) and [W3C public-webapps](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/) mailing lists. Re. mutation observers, I believe they're only available in very recent WebKit browsers, so you can try them out but not really use them on the general web.

Comment: @Derek: I'd suggest in this case using `DOMNodeInserted` (which you can feature test to check for browser support) and fall back to some kind of polling (e.g. regularly checking the new element's `parentNode` is non-null, or (better) checking that it has a `Document` ancestor).

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is an event for that. But you can append a property to the newly created element telling your script it is appended. You could do something like:

```
function appendSignal(el,toElement){
  to.appendChild(el);
  el.isAppended = true;
}

var nwdiv = document.createElement('div');
// do stuff with nwdiv
appendSignal(nwdiv,document.body);
//doing other stuff
if (nwdiv.isAppended) {
  /* nwdiv.offsetHeight should be available... */
}
```

Comment: There is such an event. See ThiefMaster's answer.

Comment: Right, forgot about that. It's not applic. for all browsers though

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers will initialise these attributes as soon as you've added it to the DOM.  It needs to be in the DOM so CSS rules can be applied.

So you won't need to receive an event, just adding the element to the DOM as soon as it is created usually works.

But if you find the attributes you need are *not* initialised immediately, you can separate that code into another function (like you would for an event handler) and invoke it using `setTimeout(otherFunction, 0)` with no delay.  Once your JavaScript has finished executing, the browser will respond to your DOM changes accordingly, and then immediately invoke your other function.  This is kind of like having the event, but firing it yourself.